# Rectangles clear each other when moving on canvas

Tags: javascript, html-canvas

I am having this problem after moving rectangles, they seem to delete one another.
Most probably it is a problem with clearRect(...) method.
This is the clean function I am using:

```
clean: function(element){
        // All default values clean all the screen
        if(typeof element.x === 'undefined'){
            element.x = 0;
        }

        if(typeof element.y === 'undefined'){
            element.y = 0;
        }

        if(typeof element.width === 'undefined'){
            element.width = canvas.width;
        }

        if(typeof element.height === 'undefined'){
            element.height = canvas.height;
        }

        // In case values are entered
        if(element.type === 'rectangle'){
            ctx.clearRect(element.x,element.y,element.width,element.height);
        }
    }
```

This is the rendering

```
rect: function(element){
    // Check if color is defined
    if(typeof element.color === 'undefined'){
        element.color = 'black';
    }
    else{
        ctx.fillStyle = element.color;
    }

    // Draw the rectangle
    ctx.fillRect(element.x,element.y,element.width,element.height);
}
```

[image: The problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearing the screen is only one half of the puzzle. I'm going to bet you also only re-draw the rectangles **if**/when they move. To confirm, you could make the red cube continue to move across the screen, I would expect there to be no graphical glitches.

**The solution:** Draw everything (on screen) every frame. There are fancier ways to deal with this, but they are not necessary for most, if not all, projects.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Just noticed that. It doesn't clear the red one. Also, I did not want to draw everything since it needs more processing and the squares are redrawn without moving. I do not know if this is ok though.

Comment: It seems inefficient to draw everything all the time, but graphics cards are really good at what they do and most per-processing that we *think* is speeding things up is actually just getting in the GPU's way. I don't know enough about it to describe it well, but I know that GPUs to a lot of optimizing to figure out how to efficiently draw the given scene. Basically: you just just draw everything (on screen) all the time.

Comment: Please note: You shouldn't draw EVERYTHING. Only draw things in view, this is important. If you have a huge tilemap and decide to draw everything, you will pay.

Comment: Thanks, I mentioned that in my comment, but I have updated my answer

Comment: @JohnMcDonald Sorry, should have read the comments. :) PS: Disappointed to see you got rid of Asteroid Outpost. :(

Comment: I have got to say, I got very satisfied with your answer @John. I tried to redraw the rects when they were stationary, then when they moved they turned white, then they turned to normal. I had to redraw again when they are stationary and a different redraw when they moved. This was the solution, but somehow it seems to me a little suspicious especially since I am using different methods. I tried to use the stationary redraw within the move method, then it didn't work. The reason why, I really do not know but really want to know!!!